# ¿Como hacer una validación personalizada en asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Quisiera saber como puedo referenciar el valor de un atributo para hacer una validación en asp.net c#. El atributo que deseo referenciar para poder hacer la validación con el método isValid() es kilometraje, el cual lo llamo como vehiculo.kilometraje. Esto para llevar realizar la validación de que el kilometraje de cambio de aceite sea mayor al kilometraje. Les dejo el código.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DiferenciaDeKilometrajeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    Model.Vehiculo elVehiculo = new Model.Vehiculo();

    public override bool IsValid(object valores)
    {
        try
        {
            int kilometraje = elVehiculo.kilometraje;
            var proximoCambioDeAceite = Convert.ToInt32(valores);

                return proximoCambioDeAceite > kilometraje;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return base.IsValid(valores);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto que planteas se realaciona con `Data Annotations`,  usa el atributo en la clase model que utilices en el action para validar si `IsValid`

[MVC 4: Custom Validation Data Annotation Attribute](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/mvc-4-custom-validation-data-annotation-attribute/)

entiendo que ese atributo lo utilizas de la siguiente forma

```
public class VehiculoModel{
   //otras propiedades

   [DiferenciaDeKilometraje]
   public int kilometraje {get;set;}
}
```

coo veras la propiedad esta decorada con el atributo que defines

Si es asi entonces si dentro del atributo utilizas

```
int kilometraje = Convert.ToInt32(value);
```

en el parametro `value` tendras el valor de la propiedad

Ahora bien si quieres acceder a la instancia de la clase que lanza la validacion usa la linea

```
var model = (Model.Vehiculo)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
```

no tienes que hacer un `new` de una nueva instancia, tienes que usar el contexto

[How To Do Custom Validation Using ValidationAttribute of ASP.NET MVC](http://dotnetmentors.com/mvc/how-to-do-custom-validation-using-validationattribute-of-aspnet-mvc.aspx)